# How to run multiple commands in one Github Actions Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint, github-actions

What is the right way for running multiple commands in one `action`?

### For example:

I want to run a python script as `action`. Before running this script I need to install the `requirements.txt`.

#### I can think of several options:

- Create a `Dockerfile` with the command `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` in it.
- Use the `python:3` image, and run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the `entrypoint.sh` file before running the arguments from `args` in `main.workflow`.
- use both `pip install` and `python myscript.py` as `args`

### Another example:

I want to run a script that exists in my repository, then compare 2 files (its output and a file that already exists).

This is a process that includes **two commands**, whereas in the first example, the `pip install` command can be considered **a building command** rather than a test command.

### the question:

Can I create another Docker for another command, which will contain the output of the previous Docker?

I'm looking for guidelines for the location of the command in `Dockerfile`, in `entrypoint` or in `args`.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can run multiple commands using a pipe  `|` on the `run` attribute. Check this out:

```
name: My Workflow

on: [push]

jobs:
  runMultipleCommands:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v1
     - run: |
        echo "A initial message"
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        echo "Another message or command"
        python myscript.py
        bash some-shell-script-file.sh -xe
     - run: echo "One last message"
```

On my tests, running a shell script like `./myscript.sh` returns a ``. But running it like `bash myscript.sh -xe` worked like expected.

[My workflow file](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/blob/a151c0e4966cb7da38523d3591ea7581ab4f62ee/.github/workflows/multiple.yml) | 
[Results](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/commit/a151c0e4966cb7da38523d3591ea7581ab4f62ee/checks#step:3:1)

If you want to run this **inside the docker machine**, an option could be run some like this on you `run` clause:

```
docker exec -it pseudoName /bin/bash -c "cd myproject; pip install -r requirements.txt;"
```

---

Regard to the "create another Docker for another command, which will contain the output of the previous Docker", you could use [multistage-builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) on your dockerfile. Some like:

```
## First stage (named "builder")
## Will run your command (using add git as sample) and store the result on "output" file
FROM alpine:latest as builder
RUN apk add git > ./output.log

## Second stage
## Will copy the "output" file from first stage
FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder ./output.log .
RUN cat output.log
# RUN your checks
CMD []
```

This way the `apk add git` result was saved to a file, and this file was copied to the second stage, that can run any check on the results.

Comment: If you run into a weird error, verify the whitespace. Delete it and use tabs to indent again.

Comment: Just a note that if you specify `run` twice for the same `name` heading, you get an error: "The workflow is not valid ... 'run' is already defined". Though your example doesn't use the `name` key under `steps`.

Comment: I had issues with this, it was ignoring whitespace even after using the `|`. Eventually, I got it to work simply by using semicolons at the end of each line which, when the action ignores whitespace, is a valid bash command.

Comment: @Seth I didn't find any reference on this.. maybe you should create a new question here, with your script, to make easy to find a solution. You can send me the question link here if you want.