# Github Action js file return string to be saved in a variable

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, action, github-actions

I have a `js` file like this, which should return me a string to use later in the `action`:

action.js

```js
async function getData(){
 const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Meet_Truffle%21.jpg/440px-Meet_Truffle%21.jpg";
 return url;
}

getData().then((url) => {
  return url;
});
```

I did a similar thing but it doesn't seem to work, can you tell me how I can do it?

Pull.yml

```
- name: Url
  run: node ./action.js >> $URL

- uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@v1
  id: downloadfile
  name: Download the file
  with:
       url: $URL
       target: assets/
```

Comment: Actually, you should first set the variable by using: `run: URL=$(node ./action.js)`, and then execute `run: echo "URL=$URL" >> $GITHUB_ENV` to set URL as environment variable in the workflow, before being able to use `url: ${{ env.URL }}` as action input.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: It doesn't seem to work.
https://pastebin.com/MQMBZW7K

Comment: You need to use `run: |` (with a pipe) to run multiline commands (cf [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726429/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-one-github-actions-docker)). That might be the issue in the link you shared. I added the full answer with the updated workflow below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to attribute the string to a variable before adding it as a ENV variable in the workflow Github Context.

However, to make it work, you can't use directly `return url;` in the `.js` file. You will also need `console.log(url);` to print the url value to the console.

**Your workflow would look like this:**

```yaml
- name: Url
  run: |
     URL=$(node ./action.js)
     echo "URL=$URL" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@v1
  id: downloadfile
  name: Download the file
  with:
       url: ${{ env.URL }}
       target: assets/
```

**And the action.js file might look like this (I'm not familiar with node):**

```
async function getData(){
 const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Meet_Truffle%21.jpg/440px-Meet_Truffle%21.jpg";
 return url;
}

getData().then((url) => {
  console.log(url);
  return url;
});
```

You can find an example in this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1924534140) with python and node. The [workflow implementation can be found here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester24.yml).

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/0k0scsLp
Not working

Comment: Could you try adding a `echo $URL` command before adding the variable to the $GITHUB_ENV to check if it has been set as expected?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV50F.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us8ys.png

Comment: In that case, I believe the problem might be related to the way the `.js` file returns the url. Could you try **printing** it instead of returning it in the `action.js` file?

Comment: What do you intend to print it?

Comment: You can see above what the js file is like.

Comment: I've tested it using python, you can find the workflow run [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5397973830?check_suite_focus=true) and the workflow file [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester24.yml) and the python script [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/test_workflow24.py). However, to make it work, I add to use `print` in python, it doesn't work with return. Will make a test with node.

Comment: I made it work using `console.log("url");` instead of return. Here is the [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1924534140) and the [.js file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/test_workflow24.js). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thx, so the return is of no use from what I understand.

Comment: It's of no use if you only use the file on a github action workflow. If you use it somewhere else it can still be useful.

Comment: I understand, does env accept string array format?

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20476002/156613112-aae62ba5-72c1-48f3-a3cd-cc2fbd32f824.png

Comment: I don't think you can add the array directly in an env variable, but it could work using an [object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#object-filters). I saw you ask another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341486/github-action-assign-a-variable-of-type-env-an-array-of-strings