# Github action assign a variable of type env an array of strings

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, action, github-actions

I am having the following problem what you see in the image.

I have a.js file which returns me an array of url strings.
Then I should assign this array to an `env` variable as seen in the example below, but I get the following error.

You can tell me where I'm wrong.

[image]

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  
name: Test Download Multifile
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Check out current commit
     
      - name: Url
        run: |
         URL=$(node ./actionMultifile.js)
         echo $URL
         echo "URL=$URL" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

actionMultifile.js

```js
async function getData(){
 const url = [
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg/440px-Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg",
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG/440px-Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG"
 ]
 return url;
}

getData().then((url) => {
 console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you need to set the URL env variable using [multiline strings](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings)

This is because the URL variable here isn't saved like this:

```
['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg/440px-Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG/440px-Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG']
```

But like this:

```
[
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg/440px-Tyrannosaurus_rex_Sue_at_FMNH.jpg',
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG/440px-Mosasaurus_beaugei_34.JPG'
]
```

Therefore, you workflow should look like this:

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout the repository content to github runner.

      - name: Setup Node Version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14 # Install the node version needed

      - name: set multiline env var
        run: |
          echo 'URL<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
          node ./actionMultifile.js >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Then, be careful, you won't be able to use the `${{ env.URL }}` variable directly, otherwise it will only print the first line (`[`) and break. You need to use it between quotes (`"`).

**For example:**

```yaml
      - name: use env var
        run: echo "${{ env.URL }}"

      - name: use env var directly
        run: echo "$URL"
```

**I tested it here if you want to take a look:**

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester25.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5411979875?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: Using `EOF` I get something like this as a value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2mCh.png

These `\ n` give me problems.

Comment: Instead as it was before I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx872.png

The value of the array is right, but I have problems with env.

Comment: Now I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did those `\n` came from? As I used exactly the same js file as yours, the behavior should be the same. Do you want to share your repository (if public)?

Comment: Thx, in the end maybe I solved it, but I didn't echo.